# How to clear objects in a listviewbuilder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to control listviewbuilder from outside the listview in flutter?
In a textfield I can use a controller like so: controller: Textcontroller. Can I do something similar in listviewbuilder to clear all the objects in it?

So to be exact. My code looks something like this

```
Expanded(
                child: new ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: List.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){

                 

                    return new Card(

                     //all stuff with data
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

....
How would I do so that when called from another function it removes all the items in the listview?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Store class that holds this list along with list manipulation methods, then you can use `provider` for example to access that class and render that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable in the state of your widget:

```
var _clear = false;
```

When this variable is true, the list will be cleared and when it's false, the list will be displayed. You can use `setState` to toggle this variable. Setting the `itemCount` of the `ListView.builder` to 0 clears the list.

Full code:

```
 var _clear = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Text('clear'),
              color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _clear = true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('add'),
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _clear = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: _clear ? 0 : 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 300,
                  child: Card(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('$index'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```